# How to push array elements asynchronously

Tags: rxjs

I'm looking for a simple way to push array elements asynchronously every second. This code works fine - it sends 2 and in a second 55:

```
Rx.Observable.from([2, 55])
  .zip(Rx.Observable.interval(1000), x => x);
```

Is there a simpler way to do the same thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use rxjs v4, you can make use of [`Rx.Observable.generateWithAbsoluteTime`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/generatewithabsolutetime.md). It is basically a for loop with varying time.

Or you could use `interval` like here :

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(yourArray.length).map(index => yourArray[index])
```

What I dont know is if it is simpler.

Comment: Thank you!  For my purposes, your second solution was more readable than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use toArray()

```
Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .take(3)
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) and [`withLatestFrom`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-withLatestFrom) but this really depends what you're trying to do.

By the way, using `.zip` in this situation is probably not ideal because `.zip` emits only when it has *Nth* item from all source Observables which is what you usually don't want.